# Autoclick submit button at several pages in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it posible to make autoclicker that will open  some page then click submit button on that page,
automatically open some other page and then click sumbit and do that for 15 pages for example?

(Or  links are login-required but I have login info ofcourse)

All I want is to write javascript or jquery code that will open that pages (not mine),
and click submit button on them.
It would be nice it could work on android browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://seleniumhq.org/

"Selenium automates browsers. What you do with that power is entirely up to you. Primarily it 
is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) also be automated as well."

Answer (score 0):

You can write a chrome extension for that and use content-scripts to do your job. I can't find other way to make js do the job if you don't own the website